# moment.locale(String) is not working when using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap3 datetimepicker and I'd like to change calendar date/time format to browser's locale setting.

I'm using requirejs to load modules asynchronously.

```
var global_component = 'my custom path...';

var require = {
  paths: {
    // Components.
    'jquery': global_component + '/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    'moment': global_component + '/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min'
  }
};

define(['jquery', 'moment', function ($, moment) {

  var mylocale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.languages[0];
  moment.locale(mylocale);

  console.log(moment.locale());
});
```

I expect the global locale of moment class would be changed to "zh", but it is still "en". Any thoughts for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there is no locale in momentjs called 'zh', only 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk' and 'zh-tw': https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale.

Make sure that `myLocale` is one of those values.